# Textbox to Accept only decimal Value and should append 2 zero after decimal

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, decimal

I was in middle of validating my page where i have 3 textboxes. 1st Textbox for selecting Date, 2nd for inserting Decimal value, 3rd again for inserting decimal value.

Actually what actually i'm trying is, if suppose user enter some value like 123 instead of 123.00 than textbox should by itself append .00 at the end of value inserted by user to make it decimal. Here is my **Javascript** code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
});

function ValidateAddNewCourseCharge() {
var EffectiveDate = $.trim($("[id$='txtFromDate']").val());
var AdminCharge = $.trim($("[id$='txtAdminCharges']").val().attr("#.00"));
var OtherCharge = $.trim($("[id$='txtOtherCharges']").val().attr("#.00"));

isValidDate(EffectiveDate);
if (EffectiveDate == "__-__-____") {
    showErrorMessagePopUp("Please select Date!");
    return false;
}
else {
    if (isValidDate(EffectiveDate) == false) {
        showErrorMessagePopUp("Please Select Valid Date for Course Amount!");
        return false;
    }
}

if (AdminCharge == "") {
    showErrorMessagePopUp("Please Enter Admin Charge!");
    return false;
}
else {
    if (isValidPrice(AdminCharge) == false) {
        showErrorMessagePopUp("Please Enter Valid Admin Amount!");
        return false;
    }
    if (AdminCharge == checkPrice(AdminCharge))
    {
        showErrorMessagePopUp("Please Enter Valid Admin Amount!");
        return false;
    }
}

if (OtherCharge == "") {
    showErrorMessagePopUp("Please Enter Other Charge!");
    return false;
}
else {
    if (isValidPrice(OtherCharge) == false) {
        showErrorMessagePopUp("Please Enter Valid Other Amount!");
        return false;
    }
    if (OtherCharge == checkPrice(OtherCharge)) {
        showErrorMessagePopUp("Please Enter Valid Other Amount!");
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
}

function isValidDate(number) {
var regex = /^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$/
return regex.test(number);
}

function isValidPrice(number) {
var regex = /^\d{0,12}(\.\d{0,2})?$/
return regex.test(number);
}

function checkPrice(el) {
var ex = /^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/;
el.value = parseFloat(el.value).toFixed(2);
if (ex.test(el.value) == false) {
    el.value = '';
}
}
```

I'm calling this function on button click.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAddCharge" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success"  OnClick="btnAddCharge_Click" OnClientClick="return ValidateAddNewCourseCharge();" />
```

Comment: javascript has a comfort function called .toFixed, in your case, you want to do .toFixed(2) to your value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed Please note that it will return a <string> instead of a number. You can update the textbox value by listening to the .keyup event and by applying some additional rules.

Comment: Ya i have already tried what u said, but still its not working in my case. function checkPrice(el) in this function i've called that .toFixed(2) but still its not appending

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem last week

this is what i came up with (depthUnit is set elsewhere e.g "m" or "ft" )

```
function manageUnitField(inputBox) {
$(inputBox).on("blur", function() {  //clicking off the inputbox causes the formatting
    var value = ($(this).val()).replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ''); //remove non-numeric and keep decimals decimals
    var i = 0; //
    value = value.replace(/\./g, function() { return i++ === 0 ? '.' : ''; }); //remove all but the first decimal
    value = value.replace(/^0+/, ''); // remove leading zeroes 
    // append depth unit
    if (value == "") {
        value = 0 + depthUnit;
    } else value = value + depthUnit;
    if (value.indexOf('.') == 0) {
        value = 0 + value;
    }
    $(this).val(value);
}).focus(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 0 + depthUnit) {
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
```

}

you can essentially use the depthUnit example to append ".00" if there isn't any decimals or nothing after the decimal

**EDIT**

and you can also use

```
Math.round(number*100)/100
```

to round to 2 decimal places

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the following way. Bear in mind that this is a **demo** and you need to adapt this to suit your needs.

```js
$("[name='number-only']").on("change", function() {
    
    var val = this.value;
    if (val.match(/\./g)) { //See if it already has a dot
        if (val.replace(/\./g, "").match(/^\d+$/) !== null) { //Check if it's number after removing the dot
            this.value = parseFloat(val, 10).toFixed(2); //Yes, so format number
        } else {
            //Not a number, so reset the input value
            //Log a msg if need be: "Only numbers allowed!";
            this.value = "";
            this.focus();
        }
    } else {
        //No dot found, so, see if it's a number        
        if (val.match(/^\d+$/) !== null) {
            this.value = parseFloat(val, 10).toFixed(2); //Yes, so format number
        } else {
            //Not a number, so reset the input value
            //Log a msg if need be: "Only numbers allowed!";
            this.value = "";
            this.focus();
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="number-only" />
```

Comment: Your code is right, but after button click i have to bind this textbox value into gridview, here its not working. Any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
function ValidateAddNewCourseCharge() {    
var AdminCharge = $.trim($("[id$='txtAdminCharges']").val());
var OtherCharge = $.trim($("[id$='txtOtherCharges']").val());
isValidDate(EffectiveDate);

if (AdminCharge == "") {
    showErrorMessagePopUp("Please Enter Admin Charge!");
    return false;
}
else {
    if (IsNumeric(AdminCharge)) {
        AdminCharge = parseFloat(AdminCharge).toFixed(2);
    }
    else {
        showErrorMessagePopUp("Admin Charge is not Valid. Please try again!");
        AdminCharge = "";
        return false;
    }
}

if (OtherCharge == "") {
    showErrorMessagePopUp("Please Enter Other Charge!");
    return false;
}
else {
    if (IsNumeric(OtherCharge)) {
        OtherCharge = parseFloat(OtherCharge).toFixed(2);
    }
    else {
        showErrorMessagePopUp("Other Charge is not Valid. Please try again!");
        OtherCharge = "";
        return false;
    }
}    
return true;
}

function IsNumeric(input) {
var RE = /^-{0,1}\d*\.{0,1}\d+$/;
// var RE = /^-{0,1}\d*\.{0,1}\d{2}$/; To Enable user to enter only decimal number
return (RE.test(input));
}
```

This work's fine...